# DPDK NIC doesn't receive any data from the other end

Tags: dpdk

I have PC A connected to PC B via an ethernet cable.
One NIC from PC A is bound to DPDK.

```
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:1f.6 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:15d8 net_e1000_em
```

and is waiting/polling in rte_eth_rx_burst

I want to send something (just a ping) from PC B.

I've setup an IP to PC B and tried to ping another IP from that interface subnet.
Also, I've tried to configure PC B interface also as a DPDK and used a basic send app, but again nothing:

```
if (port_init(mbuf_pool) != 0) {
                    rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init port %"PRIu8 "\n", 0);
    }
    struct Message {
            char data[10];
    };
    struct ether_hdr *eth_hdr;
    struct Message obj = {{'H','e','l','l','o','2','0','1','8'}};
    struct Message *msg;

    struct ether_addr s_addr = {{0x94,0xC6,0x91,0x14,0xAB,0xDD}};
    struct ether_addr d_addr = {{0x94,0xC6,0x91,0x14,0xAB,0xDD}};
    uint16_t ether_type = 0x0a00;

    struct rte_mbuf * pkt[BURST_SIZE];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<BURST_SIZE;i++) {
            pkt[i] = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(mbuf_pool);
            eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkt[i],struct ether_hdr*);
            eth_hdr->d_addr = d_addr;
            eth_hdr->s_addr = s_addr;
            eth_hdr->ether_type = ether_type;
            msg = (struct Message*) (rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkt[i],char*) + 
sizeof(struct ether_hdr));
            *msg = obj;
            int pkt_size = sizeof(struct Message) + sizeof(struct 
ether_hdr);
            pkt[i]->data_len = pkt_size;
            pkt[i]->pkt_len = pkt_size;
    }

    uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(0,0,pkt,BURST_SIZE);
```

No bytes are received on my DPDK NIC.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the pings form B to A. Most probably the DPDK application does not answer ARP requests.

   To fix: make sure you have added a correct static ARP entry on host B with `arp -s`.
2. Regarding the basic DPDK send. It has the same source and destination MACs, which is obviously wrong.

   To fix: put the correct `s_addr` and `d_addr` of hosts B and A.